# Excel function to assign certain value to specific attributes while not ignoring blank cells

Tags: excel

Here's what my excel table looks like:

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXe4r.png)

I want to populate a column called primary code, where it lists the primary code associated with that value.  Essentially, I would like primary code to be 10 for Facility ID=1 and Facility Name=X Site and 15 where Facility ID=1 and Facility Name=Z Site.  However, I can't figure out a simple IF function to use because of those blank spaces in the data.  The blank spaces essentially mean that the row takes on the value of the previous row.  It's not feasible for me to try to fill in those blank cells because my actual data has more than 500,000 observations.

Basically, I need to figure out a code that assigns each facility of the same name the same primary code, which should be the first code listed in that section of facility names.  If anyone has any insights, that would really help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to fill in the blank values, you could create a lookup column and then reference that column with a VLOOKUP.

In this example I create a new lookup column as column A, using a formula of:

```
=C2 & "-" & D2 & "-" & E2
```

Then I created the Primary Code column in G, using this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2 & "-" & D2 & "-Primary",A:F, 6, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly!  Really helpful since my excel cannot process trying to find that many blanks to replace due to the size of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick method to fill in the blanks.
Highlight the columnn you want to fill in
On the Home tab go to Find&Select
Go to Special
check Blanks "k"
Hit Enter and all blanks in the column will be selected
Then type in = and hit the up arrow and then hold ctrl and hit enter

This should populate all the blanks with the value in the cell above it.

Finally copy and paste values in the column and that should let your IF statement work.